# Is the jitter buffer (latency) size in webrtcbin static or dynamic?

Tags: gstreamer

Just looking at the latency value of the jitter buffer here (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c#webrtcbin:latency).

Is this is a static jitter buffer of 200 ms (default), and if it is, is there any particular reason why it wouldn't be dynamic such as it is in vanilla WebRTC? For example if packet loss is zero and jitter is low, is it basically adding unnecessary latency (as far as I can tell)?

According to: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpjitterbuffer.html?gi-language=c

> The rtpjitterbuffer will wait for missing packets up to a configurable
> time limit using the latency property.

However in my testing there is a linear correlation between that value and the output latency.

Example

```
100 ms == 100+ ms of latency
200 ms == 200+ ms of latency
500 ms == 500+ ms of latency
```

This latency relationship may also only occur when some elements such as a `compositor` are downstream from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latency` property is used to set the `latency` property of the `rtpbin` element and `size-time` property of rtpbin storage (to latency + 50ms):
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/03ac9692405d1fdfb21778f664ac7cdecd1338c1/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/ext/webrtc/gstwebrtcbin.c#L8274-8278

So we are only interested in the behavior of the [`rtpbin`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpbin.html).

`rtpbin` creates [`rtpjitterbuffer`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpjitterbuffer.html) and transparently propagates properties such as `latency` down to it. E.g. it also propagates `buffering-mode`, which defaults to `RTP_JITTER_BUFFER_MODE_SLAVE`, to the [`mode` property of the `rtpjitterbuffer`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpjitterbuffer.html?gi-language=c#rtpjitterbuffer:mode).

This latency is static, because in GStreamer dynamic latency is supposed to be implemented by observing the metrics and adjusting the `latency` parameter of the elements from the outside: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/latency.html?gi-language=c#dynamically-adjusting-latency The jitter buffer is static, but you can implement your favourite adaptive jitter buffer algorithm by changing the `latency` property of `webrtcbin` in runtime and it will be propagated down to `rtpjitterbuffer`.

Comment: You mentioned the mode being propagated which can be (none, slave, buffer or sync). What do they mean in this context?

Comment: This affects how exactly the buffer is used, but there is no documentation on the algorithms expect the source code it seems. I mentioned it only as an example of a property that `rtpbin` propagates to `rtpjitterbuffer` but is not named exactly the same (`buffering-mode` vs `mode`). Still, you can control most `rtpjitterbuffer` properties by changing the corresponding `rtpbin` properties, the easiest way to find out the correspondence is unfortunately checking the source code.

Comment: What I found is that its propagating the latency (+50) to RTPStorage https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/03ac9692405d1fdfb21778f664ac7cdecd1338c1/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/ext/webrtc/gstwebrtcbin.c#L7806-7816. I think this would result in a static behaviour in terms of how long packets are buffered for (which by default is at least 250 ms).

Comment: It says that this is for FEC. but I can't explain the linear relationship otherwise. As far as I understand, slave mode just sends the packets through (in contrast to buffer mode).

Comment: Outside of this property, wouldn't slave mode mean that the packets are 'not' statically delayed by x amount?